# Loops and Updates in DBT

Tags: dbt

I have a very unique problem. I want to update a table in dbt using another dbt and having a counter that hunts for new values and then it updates the column. For eg.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;


DECLARE @R INT;

SET @R = 2;

WHILE @R<10

BEGIN

    UPDATE PER 

        SET PER.CDS_ID = PERNext.CDS_ID

    FROM #P PER

    INNER JOIN #E PERNext ON (PER.web_prfl_id = PERNext.web_prfl_id AND RN = @R)

    WHERE PER.CDS_ID IS NULL AND PERNext.CDS_ID IS NOT NULL

SET @R = @R+1

END
```

RN is row number available in E table which partitions by the create date.
I know we can do update statements in post hook but how to have a counter and then do the update?
Thanks,

Comment: 1) did you mean "table in dbt using another ~~dbt~~ table"? 2) can you provide two small sample tables and what you want the end result to be? 3) have you read the [Jinja & marcos dbt docs page](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/jinja-macros) already?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding that you're trying to perform the UPDATE statement within dbt, no matter what the job is.

So there are 2 options you could try:

1. Using incremental mode. Have a read on [this](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models)
2. Would be easier that using `dbt marco` - it is something the same as procedure, but within dbt. Have a read [this](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/jinja-macros)